# setView with ChildViewController

Tags: ios, ipad

I have ViewController with child, it's works great, but when I change root view to another, and then return back the root view:

```
-(void)showSearchResultView
{
    self.searchView.frame = self.view.frame;
    __rootView = self.view;
    [self setView:self.searchView];
}

-(void)hideSearchResultView
{
    if(__rootView) [self setView:__rootView];
    __rootView = nil;
}
```

I'm getting the exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', 
reason: 'child view controller:<SlideViewController> should have parent view controller:
<UINavigationController> but actual parent is:<MainViewController>'
```

What is the proper way to change root view with child view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Just remove the children root views and add it again.

```
-(void)showSearchResultView
{
    self.searchView.frame = self.view.frame;
    __rootView = self.view;
    [self setView:self.searchView];

    for(UIViewController* vc in self.childViewControllers){
        [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

-(void)hideSearchResultView
{
    if(__rootView) [self setView:__rootView];
    __rootView = nil;

    for(UIViewController* vc in self.childViewControllers){
        vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For changing root view you have to remove rootviewcontroller from navigation stack.
Like :

NSMutablerray *controllers = [self.navigationController viewcontrollers];

[controllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];

it will remove the rootviewController and name way you can add new view Controllers.

[controllers addObjectAtIndex:0];

Note:- This code syntax might be incorrect .this is just a approach.

Update:-

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

RootViewController *root = [[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

[viewControllers insertObject:root atIndex:0];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

This way you can change your root view.

Comment: How can I remove view controller, where actually is? And I can change the view, when it's viewcontroller haven't children just use setView property.